# Получить имя и фамилию из FB по id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

Нужно вытащить из фейсбука по id человека картинку, имя и фамилию. Картинку я вытащил таким запросом:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100001037095200/picture
```

Но как вытащить имя и фамилию ? Примеры из fb api не работают, иначе бы запрос типа

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100001037095200
```

Должен был вернуть json со всеми доступными данными.

Comment: "An access token is required to request this resource" - нужно получить специальный токен

Comment: @Rikaz Не скажете как ?

Comment: @SlavikOkara, с помощью sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4